# npm start giving error

Tags: node.js, npm, kraken.js

I have installed KrakenJs on Windows 7. I have created project by using following command :

Yo Kraken

When I tried to run the project, it is giving following error (even after restarting system) :

```
    E:\nodejs\test\kraken\Dust-01>npm start

> dust-01@0.1.0 start E:\nodejs\test\kraken\Dust-01
> node index.js

Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1020:19)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1127:5)
    at bind (E:\nodejs\test\kraken\Dust-01\node_modules\kraken-js\index.js:139:33)
    at _fulfilled (E:\nodejs\test\kraken\Dust-01\node_modules\kraken-js\node_modules\q\q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (E:\nodejs\test\kraken\Dust-01\node_modules\kraken-js\node_modules\
q\q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (E:\nodejs\test\kraken\Dust-01\node_modules\kraken-js\node_mo
dules\q\q.js:760:13)
    at E:\nodejs\test\kraken\Dust-01\node_modules\kraken-js\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
    at flush (E:\nodejs\test\kraken\Dust-01\node_modules\kraken-js\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)

E:\nodejs\test\kraken\Dust-01>
```

Can some one guide me what I am doing wrong and how it can be rectified

Comment: Do you have permission to open the port you're trying to start the server on?  Are you certain nothing else is already running on that port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into next two possibilities:

1. Try opening your command prompt 'As Administrator', that shall solve the issue if you are lacking permissions to open port.
2. Temporarily change the port used in Kraken to something irregular and long, example: 32482

Then move on from this, if 1st - then you have solved an issue, if 2nd - you are very likely trying to open a port, which is already used by other application.